# Collecting arctan terms

Tags: trigonometry

How do you simplify $\arctan(x) +\arctan(2x) + \arctan(3x)$ into the form $a\cdot\arctan(b\cdot x)$?

I'm assuming this is possible because when I plotted it on CAS it produces a graph that looks like a dilated arctan graph.

Comment: @ Adam Did you get the same plot on CAS? If not please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$arctan(x) + arctan(y)= arctan[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]$$

with: $x y<1$

$$arctan(x) + arctan(y)= \pi+arctan[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]$$

with: $x >0$  and $x y>1$

and

$$arctan(x) + arctan(y)= -\pi+arctan[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]$$

with: $x <0$  and $x y>1$

Addition so far gives me:

$$\arctan (x)+\arctan (2 x)+\arctan (3 x)=\arctan \left(\frac{6 x \left(x^2-1\right)}{11 x^2-1}\right)$$

Look's not very friendly to me.

Comment: There are three arguments here.

Comment: Yes, I see. But if we can add two terms, it should not be to
difficult to three terms. This was a hint adding arctan, not a
complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let the x cross-over limit be  x = a  for large angle inverse function in third quadrant.

For small angles we can use the formula

$$\tan (\tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(y) + \tan^{-1}(z)) = \dfrac{x +y+z - x y z}{1- x y -y z -z x } $$

which simplifies to

$$ \dfrac{6 x (1-x^2) }{(1-11 x^2)}  $$

so given expression becomes

for $ x < a $

$$ \tan^{-1} {\dfrac{6 x (1-x^2) }{(1-11 x^2)}} $$

for $ x > a $

$$ 2\pi + \tan^{-1} {\dfrac{6 x (1-x^2) }{(1-11 x^2)}} $$

Value of $a$ is found graphically as a ~ 1 ; the cross-over evaluation not clear in 
calculation. Plot is not antisymmetric with respect to origin (asymptotes are $\pi, ~ -2.4 $ ). First plot is raw, domain not corrected. Posting plots to trace the puzzling error further. Also may be in form $ c+ a\cdot\arctan(b\cdot x). $

[image: ArcTanAngsPuzzle]